# Separate different applications running in different workspaces

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock

How can I set the taskbar (Ubuntu dock) to show applications running in the current workspace only? Currently clicking on it shows all the different locations where the application is running.

[image]

Here, 2 Firefox windows are running in different workspaces, so I do not want all of them being displayed in all workspaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute the following command to have the dock list windows on the current workspace only:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces true
```